# C Program at runtime to execute the shell with respect to the input and output In JAVA

Tags: java, c, runtime, exec, output

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class runtime {

    public static void main ( String [] args) {
        try {
            Process proc= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash -c " + "./a.out" ); 
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter stdOutput = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream()));
            String s = "";
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
            String sendMemo = reader.readLine();
            stdOutput.write(sendMemo+"\n");
            stdOutput.flush();
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }           
        }
        catch( IOException e ) { System.out.println ( e )};         
    }
}
```

C code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("InPUt : \n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("std : %d",a);   
}
```

I want to execute C Program In JAVA. I think to use this shell Command from JAVA:

```
 runtime.getRuntime().exec
```

So i want result this:

```
print :: Input :     <-value input 5
print ::std : 5
```

but
my code is

```
value input 5
print :: Input :
print :: std : 5
```

help me please

Comment: I tried to fix your formatting, but was entirely unable to decipher your expected results and what you actually get. And seeing the `InPUt`, this don't seem to be the actual code for that output.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java program reads "5" from standard input, which is dutifully echoed, since standard input is the terminal.

Then, you are passing this to the called C program's standard input via a pipe. This pipe isn't the terminal any more, so there's no echo; the line containing "5" is read without echo, and processed. So you'll see the prompt ("InPUt"), but no echo.